# Symmetric(or undirected) Hamiltonian Cycle data sets

Tags: graph, cycle, np, graph-traversal, hamiltonian-cycle

I would like to test my recently created algorithm on large (50+ node) graphs.  Preferrably, they would specifically be challenging graphs, and known tours would exist (for at least most of them).

Problem sets for this problem do not seem as easy to find as with the TSP.  I am aware of the Flinder's challenge set available at http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/csem/research/programs/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/fhcpcs.cfm

However, they seem to be directed.  I can probably alter my algorithm to work for directed, but it will take time and likely induce bugs.  I'd prefer to know if it can work for undirected first.

Does anyone know where problem sets are available?  Thank you.

*quick edit:*

Now I am unsure if the flinder's set is directed or not....  It doesn't say.  Examples make it seem like maybe it actually is undirected.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY
Also check the in depth sequel to the video.
You can determine yourself how many nodes you want to add to the graph.
It does require you to construct the data yourself, which should be deable.
One note: the problem is about a path, not a cycle, but you can overcome this by connecting the start and end node.